# PERN stack app on Heroku syntax error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my first React.js app on Heroku. Everything seems to work fine [link to app](https://dj-bbq.herokuapp.com/) except the most important part - the Express.js REST API that I use to fetch data from my Postgres database and Stripe API is functioning normally on localhost, but when I deploy the app on Heroku, ***all the API routes I am trying to access return the same syntax error - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.***

I understand that the issue is tied to how my app routes to the API. In other words, the fetch request is not able to get to the needed endpoint and thus return this syntax error, but I can't pinpoint exactly where is the issue - am I missing a '/' somewhere, have I incorrectly set up my environment variables, etc.?

Has someone had a similar issue or maybe someone can spot the issue in my code down below?

**package.json**

```
{
...
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "homepage": "https://dj-bbq.herokuapp.com",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.14.15",
    "node": "14.18.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formspree/react": "^2.2.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@userfront/react": "^0.2.22",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "helmet": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "stripe": "^8.195.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build",
    "dev-start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "nodemon": "nodemon server.js"
  },...
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet'); 
const cors = require('cors'); 
const path = require('path'); // Allows to access files through the server in our filesystem
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'); // Parses multipart/form-data requests, extracts the files if available, and make them available under req.files property.

/**
**  ------------- GENERAL SETUP -------------
*/

// Provides access to variables from the .env file by using process.env.REACT_APP_variable_name
    require('dotenv').config();

    const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

    const devPort = process.env.REACT_APP_server_dev_port;
    const prodPort = process.env.PORT // process.env.PORT 

    const devDomain = process.env.REACT_APP_dev_domain;
    const prodDomain= process.env.REACT_APP_prod_domain;
    
    const PORT = nodeEnv ? devPort : prodPort;
    const domain = nodeEnv ? devDomain : prodDomain;

// CORS options
const corsOptions = {
    origin: domain, // frontend_URL for heroku deployment
    credentials: true ,
    // Allows only the following HTTP requests to go through
    methods: [
        "PUT", 
        "POST", 
        "DELETE", 
        "GET",
    ],
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
        "Origin", 
        "X-Requested-With", 
        "Content-Type", 
        "Accept", 
        "Authorization",
    ],
};

//* Creates the Express server instance as "app" 
    const app = express();

//* MIDDLEWARE

// Called BETWEEN processing the Request and sending the Response in your application method.
    app.use(helmet()); // Sets many http headers to make them more secure
    app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // To allow cross origin conections (Allows our React app to make HTTP requests to Express application)        
    
    // Instead of using body-parser middleware, use the new Express implementation of the same thing
        app.use(express.json()); // To recognize the incoming Request Object (req.body) as a JSON Object
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // To recognize the incoming Request Object as strings or arrays
    app.use(fileUpload({
        createParentPath: true
    })); // Enables file uploading

//* HEROKU MIDDLEWARE

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        // To load static files or client files from here http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        // Serve static files - makes the build folder accessible to app.
            app.use(express.static(path.joins(__dirname, 'build'))); 
            // app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'))); 
    }

/**
** -------------- SERVER ----------------
*/
       
// Determines the PORT and enables LISTENing for requests on the PORT (http://localhost:8000)
       
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.debug(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
  
/**
** ------- ROUTES / ENDPOINTS ---------
*/

// Go to /test to make sure the basic API functioning is working properly
    app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('The Basic API endpoints are working.')
    });

// Imports all of the routes from ./routes/index.js
    app.use(require('./app-server/routes/allRoutes'));

// If req comes from one of these domains (origins), then allow the request with CORS.
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const corsWhitelist = [
            domain,
        ];
        if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        }
        next();
    });
```

***I have set-up a catch all route (router) for unkown routes in a different file***

```
//* HEROKU - catch all for unrecognised routes

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        // Serve index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route
            router.get('*', (req, res, next) => { // or * instead of /
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); // resolve instead of join
            })
    }
```

***And here is an example of a fetch request***

```
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        let interval;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                // const url = 'http://localhost:8000/recipes/display';
                const url = `${customProxy}/recipes/display`;
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();

                setRecipes(json);
                
            } catch(error) {
                // console.error(error);
                alert("Recipe displaying:" + error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            fetchData()
        }, 86 * 1000)
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }

    }, []); // Determine swhen to re-use useEffect, if this changes.
```

***Thank you in advance for taking the time to consider the solution for issue!***

### Update 1

I started going through my project for the n-th time and previously I followed the guides found on Heroku to deploy my PERN app. The guides recommended using [mars/create-react-app-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) to deploy the app, but after reading the documentation of this build pack it clearly says that this build pack is only meant for static react apps not react apps with its own custom node.js server.

In such cases, I am to use the [mars/heroku-cra-node](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node).

I have been following the documentation on how to set-up my folder structure, etc., but now, when I deploy the app, Heroku informs me of the following...

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node
       bash: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/d07ae047a3685d9cfb39224105301a7dbdbfbe9c/bin/detect: No such file or directory
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I understand that the idea is that my folder structure is not as required by the build pack, but I am following its documentation by the letter.

Has anyone had any experience in using this build pack to deploy a PERN app to Heroku?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with extra "s" in this line. Can you delete it and try again please? `app.use(express.static(path.joins(__dirname, 'build')))`

Comment: @Abdulhakim That was a nice find. I changed the code from "joins" to "join" and deployed the new code to Heroku, but that did not change anything. Otherwise, thanks for noticing that mistake.

Comment: May be you can remove the quotes surrounding `production`. I mean instead of `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ` maybe you can say `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== production)`. Also for the below line.

Comment: @Abdulhakim Thank you for the recommendation. I tried it, pushed it to Heroku after committing , but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that this question of mine is still unanswered.

The issue, in the end, was that I was trying to use the Heroku free plan, but my app was too "big" for that so I either needed to split the back-end and front-end into two apps or to use a paid plan.

In the end, I actually changed my hosting service provider from Heroku to Digital Ocean. The app is still on their servers and works now - https://dj-bbq-i5gdc.ondigitalocean.app/ .